# jupyter notebookで関数定義と図形の描写が行えません。

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

初めまして。基本的なことですみませんが、みんなのpythonを独学で自習しておりまして、
関数を定義して図形を描写するところでエラーが出ます。
使っているのはanacondaをインストールしたwindows10 でjupyter notebookに記述をした所です。
何がおかしいのか教えていただけませんでしょうか。
forwardは今までだったらjupyterでも使えていたのですが。

```
def circle():
    for cnt in range(36):
        forward(20)
        left(10)

for i in range(10):
    circle()
    left(36)
```

---

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-d2d558455343> in <module>()
      5 
      6 for i in range(10):
----> 7     circle()
      8     left(36)

<ipython-input-5-d2d558455343> in circle()
      1 def circle():
      2     for cnt in range(36):
----> 3         forward(20)
      4         left(10)
      5 

NameError: name 'forward' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

メニューバーの "Kernel" → "Restart & Run All" 等から、一度カーネルを再起動し上のセルからすべて実行し直してみてください。

ここで使っている `forward` 関数は Turtle というライブラリから提供されている関数ですが、このライブラリが適切に `import` されていないと Python は「`forward` 関数が見つからない」というエラーを出します。それが今回の NameError です。

具体的には、上の方のセルに次のような行があるはずです。この行を実行させて Turtle から諸々の関数を `import` すれば NameError は解消するはずです。

```
from turtle import *
```